# positive and negative correlation interpretation

Tags: correlation, interpretation

What's the interpretation of a positive/negative correlation between two variable?

Let's say I have this code in R
`cor(data$jobsatisfaction, data$age)` which gives me a negative correlation $-0.05560993$
But `cor(data$age, data$jobsatisfaction)` gives me $-0.05560993$ too
So which variable influences the other variable negative? I am confused.

Answer (score 3):

Correlation does not describe which variable influences the other. You've perhaps heard that correlation does not imply causation. This is why. You just get that there is a strength of a particular type of relationship.

Answer (score 0):

It is hardy say about "influences" using correlation. Correlation do not allow you to decide which variable influence another. Only proper experiment design, not correlation, may help you decide about influence.

Whether the value is positive or negative tell you how the one variable changes along with another.
The negative sign means that if one value is increasing, the another is decreasing or if one is decreasing another is increasing. While, the positive sign means that if one value is increasing, the other is also increasing, or if one value is decreasing, the another is also decreasing.